# Partial Fraction Decomposition (Complex Numbers)

Tags: partial-fractions

I'm going insane with this question from a previous exam:

How do I get the partial fraction decomposition of: $${15 \over (z-3i)(2z-3)}$$

I don't understand how to 'equate' anything here. If we have that $$15=a(2z-3)+b(z-3i)$$ then how am I meant to get $a$ and $b$ ? Equating $z$ terms I can get that $2a+b=0$ but I don't understand at all how to deal with the $i$ term.

Comment: $15 = (2a+b)z + (-3a-3ib)$ must hold for *all* values of $z$. That gives you *two* equations for $a$ and $b$.

Comment: "*Equating z terms  I can get...*" $\;-\;$ Then equate *non*-$z$ terms next.

Comment: @dxiv I still don't understand = how does $-15 = 3a + 3bi$ help at all?

Comment: @ThunderHex At that point you have two linear equations in two unknowns, which should be easy to solve for $a,b \in \mathbb C$.

Comment: @dxiv I'm totally lost here. I don't understand how to deal with $3bi$

Comment: @ThunderHex By elimination, for example, the first equation is $b=-2a$, then the second equation is $-15=3a-6ai$. What's the difficulty with solving that for $a$?

Comment: @dxiv Managed to get it, thanks. We were never taught complex numbers so I'm very rusty

Answer (score 1):

You want to find $A,B$ such that
$$
\dfrac{15/2}{(z-3i)(z-\frac 32)}=\frac{A}{z-3i} + \frac{B}{z-\frac 32}
$$

So, what you need to equate is
$$
B(z-3i) +A(z-\frac 32) = \frac{15}{2}
$$
or,

$$
(A+B) z - (3iB+\frac 32 A) = \frac{15}{2}.
$$

Since this equality must hold for all $z$, you must have $A+B=0$ and  $3iB+\frac 32 A = -\frac{15}{2}$.

$$
\dfrac{15/2}{(z-3i)(z-\frac 32)}=-\dfrac{1+2i}{z-3i}+\frac{1+2i}{z-\frac 32}
$$

---

$$
\begin{cases}A=-B \\ (3i-\frac 32)B = -\frac{15}{2}\end{cases}\Leftrightarrow
\begin{cases}A = -1-2i \\ B=\frac{15}{2(3i-\frac 32)} = 1+2i\end{cases}
$$